# dojo custom widget won't call postCreate

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo, amd

I have a custom widget that is not working properly.  It is being instantiated, but it will not call the `postCreate` function.  I do not receive any error messages.

I have removed any extra code from the widget for testing purposes and here is the resulting code:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dijit/_WidgetBase",
        "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
        "dojox/mobile/Button",
        "dojo/text!pgonline/widgets/AttributeInspector/templates/AttributeInspector.html"],

    function(declare,
             lang,
             _WidgetBase,
             _TemplatedMixin,
             _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
             Button,
             template) {

        return declare("AttributeInspector2", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

            templateString : template,
            baseClass : "AttributeInspector2",
            postCreate : function() {
                dojo.connect(this, "onBeforeTransitionIn", lang.hitch(this, this.onPageLoad));
            },

            onPageLoad : function() {
            }
        });
    });
```

I can tell it is being instantiated because when I debug in Chrome, I can set a breakpoint on the line: `templateString : template` and it will stop on that breakpoint, but it will not stop on the breakpoint for the code inside the `postCreate` function.  The template itself is a simple HTML file that contains several `div`'s and a single `dojox.mobile.button`.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the instantiation code:

```
require(["pgonline/widgets/AttributeInspector2"], function(AttributeInspector) {

    var att = new AttributeInspector({});

att.placeAt("attributeInspector");
att.startup();

});
```

Comment: How does your widget class get instantiated?  Parser? Programmatically?

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo - I added the instantiation code to the post.

Comment: Can you mimic this behavior in a jsfiddle? I [set this one up](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/39/) similarly to yours (different event handler and module, but same widget set up and instantiation) and it works as expected.

Comment: @Default, I did the same http://jsfiddle.net/jrkeller/NNauz/ and it worked for me as well. Could it be possible your placing it before domReady?  I don't think a breakpoint on the template line indicates the widget is being instantiated-- it just means the module is loaded

Comment: @Default - I haven't used Fiddle much.  I tried to put this (http://jsfiddle.net/dgtGs/) together but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be off base, but based on your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgtGs/), the error in the console is `Uncaught Error: Invalid template`

Your template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <button data-dojo-attach-point='prevButton' data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.Button'></button>
    <button data-dojo-attach-point='nextButton'></button>
</div>
<div data-dojo-attach-point='attributes'></div>
```

Dijit requires templates to have a single root node-- so as a fix, just add a containing div to the template

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button data-dojo-attach-point='prevButton' data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.Button'></button>
        <button data-dojo-attach-point='nextButton'></button>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point='attributes'></div>
</div>
```